# Solr process gets killed immediately after starting

Tags: ubuntu, vps, java, solr

I just downloaded solr 4.8.0 from the apache website to my ubuntu 12.04, 64 Bit, 3GB ram VPS server and extracted it.
Then I installed the openjdk-7-jre using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

when I tried to start solr using the example start.jar (/solr/example/start.jar) using

```
java -jar start.jar
```

I get much output in the console but after about 15 seconds the process exits with these last lines:

```
2941 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  ? registering core: collection1
2942 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  ? user.dir=/usr/local/solr/example
2943 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  ? SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
2967 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  ? Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
2972 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [collection1] webapp=null path=null params={event=firstSearcher&q=static+firstSearcher+warming+in+solrconfig.xml&distrib=false} hits=0 status=0 QTime=30
2972 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? QuerySenderListener done.
2972 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  ? Loading spell index for spellchecker: default
2972 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  ? Loading spell index for spellchecker: wordbreak
2972 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SuggestComponent  ? Loading suggester index for: mySuggester
2972 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester  ? reload()
2973 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.SolrSuggester  ? build()
2991 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  ? [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@3803cdb4[collection1] main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_5:15:nrt _3(4.8):C42)}
Killed
root@myawsmhostname:/usr/local/solr/example#
```

It just says **Killed** in the last line but I didn't do anything and I didn't touch the keyboard while it was running.

Btw: I am able to access the web-ui at port 8983. I can even browse that ui but after 15-30 seconds -- baam the process gets killed ._________.

**Does anyone know that issue or know a workaroung?**

I have searched all over the net but couldn't find a solution, that's why I assume that it's not an solr or jetty error, more a Java or Ubuntu thing.

Comment: Check your logs (`/var/log/kern.log`). It's probably getting killed by the OOM-killer.

Comment: @faker the file is one byte "big" and last modified when I set up the Server (2013)

Comment: Might be at a different location then. `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog` or whatever you configured it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the java memory settings on the java command line that starts your app.   For example, you use `-Xms` for minimum heap size,  `-Xmx` for max heap size, and `-XX:MaxPermSize` for the "permanent generation" heap (a different memory pool).  Reasonable values if you are running nothing else on this 3GB server:

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Without knowing more about your app and java memory tuning, you'll find this to be a trial and error process.  You can probably increase -Xmx a bit without running out of memory.

Comment: Still gets killed. App is Solrs standart start.jar. Java memory tuning? Everything default, fresh install of the opendjdk jre. syslog file says nothing about java, messages too. Is there any Java-specific log file on the system?

Comment: sorry for slow response, but for the record, there is not likely to be a system-wide java log file.  There may be something from solr itself, but it's more likely to be the system OOM-killer that you need to find log info from.  check the output of `dmesg` for info from the OOM-killer, and try to adjust the java memory sizes a bit downward to see if that helps.  Also, note that I had a typo: `-Xmx2048` should be `-Xmx2048m`.  I've corrected the answer.